# Converting multidimensional array elements to different type

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, converters

Suppose I have this multidimensional array:

```
float[][,] vertices = { 
            new float[,]{ {0f, 1.28f}, {1.28f, 2.56f}, {3.84f, 2.56f}, {5.12f, 1.28f}, {3.84f, 0f}, {1.28f, 0f}, {0f, 1.28f} }, 
            new float[,]{ {0f, 3.83f}, {1.27f, 5.12f}, {3.87f, 5.12f}, {5.12f, 3.83f}, {5.12f, 1.26f}, {3.87f, 0f}, {1.27f, 0f}, {0f, 1.26f}, {0f, 3.83f} } 
        };
```

Now, I want to convert each subarray to an array of type `Vector2[]` where `Vector2` is a public class, which simply contains `x` and `y` properties:

```
public class Vector2 {
  public float x;
  public float y;

  public Vector2(float x, float y) { this.x = x; this.y = y }
}
```

So I want to construct Vector2 elements from Array[2] elements, which are subarrays in above `vertices` array variable.

I do it like this:

```
Array.ConvertAll(vertices[0], 
    new Converter<float[], Vector2>(verticesSequence => { return new Vector2(verticesSequence[0], verticesSequence[1]); }));
```

However, in return I receive this error message:

> Error 15  The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Array.ConvertAll(float[][],
>   System.Converter)' has some invalid
>   arguments

Comment: What are the invalild arguments?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking my question. I wonder what is wrong with my syntax.

Comment: Ah sorry I thought there might be more information in the error message (I'll see if i can work it out)

Comment: The error is simply that `Array.ConvertAll` requires a jagged array and you are passing in a multidimensional array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array, which contains two arrays, each of which contains a different number of float arrays.

`Array.ConvertAll` is suitable for converting one array into the other by specifying a mapping delegate (one to one). In this case, you don't only have to convert a single `float[,]` into a  `Vector2`. Note that you also used a `float[]` to `Vector2` converter, instead of `float[,]` to `Vector2`.

Multidimensional arrays like `float[,]` are also a bit tricky since they don't support LINQ out of the box, which it a bit harder to create a one-liner which would do all the mapping.

In other words, you will at least need a helper method to map the items of the multidimensional array:

```
public static IEnumerable<Vector2> ConvertVectors(float[,] list)
{
    for (int row = 0; row < list.GetLength(0); row++)
    {
        yield return new Vector2(list[row, 0], list[row, 1]);
    }
}
```

And then you can use that inside the `Array.ConvertAll` method:

```
var converted = Array.ConvertAll<float[,], Vector2[]>(
    vertices,
    ff => ConvertVectors(ff).ToArray());
```

Honestly, I would prefer a LINQ solution because it will infer all the generic parameters automatically:

```
var r = vertices
    .Select(v => ConvertVectors(v).ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: Well, I'm using Array.ConvertAll on vertices[0], which suppose to be float[,] array, thus the Converter should have <float[], Vector2> generic parameters, right?

Comment: @GuardianX: it should actually be `float[,], Vector2`, but I've updated the answer with full code.

Comment: @GuardianX: btw, I would prefer using a LINQ solution to do the mapping. Alternatively, if there are really many elements in these arrays, you could get some slight performance benefits by preallocating target arrays and using plain `for` loops (at the cost of code simplicity of course).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments the errors you are getting is because you were trying to pass in a multidimensional array instead of a jagged array.

For your needs it may be easier to just use a simple loop

```
List<Vector2> newList = new List<Vector2>();
foreach (float[,] array in vertices)
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++ ) 
        newList.Add(new Vector2(array[i,0], array[i,1]));
```

Note: this loops through all vertices so the outer loop may not be required for your needs.