# How to convert a multiple rank array using ConvertAll()?

Tags: c#

I want to use ConvertAll like this:

```
 var sou = new[,] { { true, false, false }, { true, true, true } };
 var tar = Array.ConvertAll<bool, int>(sou, x => (x ? 1 : 0));
```

but I got compiler error:

> cannot implicitly convert type bool[*,*] to bool[]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting multidimensional array elements to different type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25658557/converting-multidimensional-array-elements-to-different-type)

Comment: Multidimensional arrays are a nearly unsupported feature of .NET . Don't think to be able to find love for them anywhere, even in the `Array` class.

Comment: @xanatos Maybe I'm mistaken, but .NET doesn't love arrays at all. Since it's a high-level OOP environment, and C# is an OOP language from the scratch, there're few cases where you'll use an array instead of a collection. In fact, a 2D array can be expressed as `List<List<T>>`...

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer .NET loves single dimensional arrays quite enough...  Sadly there is a tradein between speed (arrays) and flexibility (everything else). Arrays are faster, but can't have extra features bolted on... You can't make a read-only array for example. But note that arrays are a building block of .NET: nearly all the collections internally use arrays (`LinkedList<>` is the sole exception I can think of)

Comment: @xanatos Yeah, I'm agree about 1D arrays... About the read-only arrays, C# team is talking about immutable types for C# 7.0 as possible language feature... https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/159

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer They are as much an array as it is a `List<T>`... The point of the array is that the IL language has opcodes to handle it directly. There are opcodes to read and to write from a single-dimensional array (`ldelem*` and `stelem*`). Any higher-level construct can't do this, unless it can force the compiler to inline the access to the array. Other problem: for certain types (nearly all the primitive types), the marshaler can do "direct" marshaling for arrays (so it doesn't need to copy the array around). This isn't possible for other collection types.

Comment: @xanatos Well, I suggested that you can use collections instead of arrays from a high-level point of view. If you're not developing a high-perf system, the advantages of arrays are useless while using specialized collections introduces good semantics in terms of solving specific domain issues. I tend to believe that semantics are prefered over extreme performance if performance doesn't matter in your domain

Answer (score 7):

You could write a straightforward conversion [extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx):

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static TResult[,] ConvertAll<TSource, TResult>(this TSource[,] source, Func<TSource, TResult> projection)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (projection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("projection");  

        var result = new TResult[source.GetLength(0), source.GetLength(1)];
        for (int x = 0; x < source.GetLength(0); x++)
            for (int y = 0; y < source.GetLength(1); y++)
                result[x, y] = projection(source[x, y]);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Sample usage would look like this:

```
var tar = sou.ConvertAll(x => x ? 1 : 0);
```

The downside is that if you wanted to do any other transforms besides projection, you would be in a pickle.

---

Alternatively, if you want to be able to use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397926.aspx) operators on the sequence, you can do that easily with regular LINQ methods. However, you would still need a custom implementation to turn the sequence back into a 2D array:

```
public static T[,] To2DArray<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int rows, int columns)
{
    if (source == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    if (rows < 0 || columns < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("rows and columns must be positive integers.");

    var result = new T[rows, columns];

    if (columns == 0 || rows == 0)
        return result;            

    int column = 0, row = 0;
    foreach (T element in source)
    {
        if (column >= columns)
        {
            column = 0;                    
            if (++row >= rows)                    
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Sequence elements do not fit the array.");                         
        }
        result[row, column++] = element;                
    }

    return result;
}
```

This would allow a great deal more flexibility as you can operate on your source array as an [IEnumerable{T}](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) sequence.

Sample usage:

```
var tar = sou.Cast<bool>().Select(x => x ? 1 : 0).To2DArray(sou.GetLength(0), sou.GetLength(1));
```

Note that the initial cast is required to transform the sequence from `IEnumerable` paradigm to `IEnumerable<T>` paradigm since a multidimensional array does not implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Most of the LINQ transforms only work on that.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is of unknown rank, you can use this extension method (which depends on the MoreLinq Nuget package). I'm sure this can be optimized a lot, though, but this works for me.

```
using MoreLinq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static Array ConvertAll<TOutput>(this Array array, Converter<object, TOutput> converter)
    {
        foreach (int[] indices in GenerateIndices(array))
        {
            array.SetValue(converter.Invoke(array.GetValue(indices)), indices);
        }
        return array;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int[]> GenerateCartesianProductOfUpperBounds(IEnumerable<int> upperBounds, IEnumerable<int[]> existingCartesianProduct)
    {
        if (!upperBounds.Any())
            return existingCartesianProduct;

        var slice = upperBounds.Slice(0, upperBounds.Count() - 1);

        var rangeOfIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, upperBounds.Last() + 1);

        IEnumerable<int[]> newCartesianProduct;
        if (existingCartesianProduct.Any())
            newCartesianProduct = rangeOfIndices.Cartesian(existingCartesianProduct, (i, p1) => new[] { i }.Concat(p1).ToArray()).ToArray();
        else
            newCartesianProduct = rangeOfIndices.Select(i => new int[] { i }).ToArray();

        return GenerateCartesianProductOfUpperBounds(slice, newCartesianProduct);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int[]> GenerateIndices(Array array)
    {
        var upperBounds = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank).Select(r => array.GetUpperBound(r));
        return GenerateCartesianProductOfUpperBounds(upperBounds, Array.Empty<int[]>());
    }
}
```